# Make Banners / Image / Iframe etc

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, banner

I have a website on PHP MySQL. I want to provide users with banners/images etc which they can place on their websites/Forum.

Anyone can use banner with link like the ones provided by Facebook. Data will be dynamic on banners so I cannot make images.

How should I proceed?

Comment: a more pointed question would make this question more answerable

Comment: I have some info on database which i want to display on banners with same iD etc. . For eg. you can see banners which users post in forum signatures or you can see the careers2.0 banners on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at PHP [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) and [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) for dynamic generation of images.

Comment: Thanks.I will look into it.    But how can i make a box (like careers2.0 box on this site on right ) which is not a image and has links etc.
Many websites provide such boxes for affiliates and advertising etc

Comment: Well, it looks like plain HTML to me! Since your users are going to put banners on their own sites, you're probably best off generating pages containing such a box using plain PHP, and letting others include it via an `iframe`.